# How to create a custom hashcode to determine if data has mutated

Tags: go

Say I have a struct type that has int64 and bools, along with embedded types that have more int64 and bool type fields.

```
type T1 struct {
   f1 int64
   f2 int64
   f3 bool
   T2 T2
}

type T2 struct {
   f4 int64
   f5 int64
   f6 bool
}
```

Now using all the structs fields/properties, I want to generate a hashcode.

The aim of this is so I can determine if the contents of the instance has changed but comparing the before/after hashcode value.

So if T1 instance has changed i.e. any of its own properties Then the value of the hash should be different.

Comment: If the types are valid for map keys, you can check their existence in a `map[T1]bool`, but in that case you could also just use the `==` operator. Otherwise you're going to have to define some sort of serialization method for your types.

Comment: To echo off @JimB, you could use encoding/gob&base64 to serialize your struct.

Comment: I don't want to serialize it, I want a hash value that is based off of the values of the fields.

Comment: @coolbreeze: you need to serialize those values *somehow* in order to generate a hash, i.e. the raw bytes need to be read by the hashing function in a consistent manner.  You can either take the path of least resistance and use a predefined encoding like `gob`, or generate your own functions/methods for writing the values to a hash function. If you want choose the latter approach, what are your goals? Hash speed, comparison speed, hash size, collision resistance, randomness?

Comment: First of all two different values can have the same hash, so to reliably determine if two values are different it is not enough to compare their hashes. And to calculate hash you need to read all fields of the struct  and do some calculations, comparison using `==` will be most likely faster.

Comment: if you need control the hash generation of the map, I suggest use a custom map, other than golang native map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
func (t *T1) Hash() uint64 {
    hb := make([]byte, 8+8+1+8+8+1)
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(hb, uint64(t.f1))
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(hb[8:], uint64(t.f2))
    if t.f3 {
        hb[16] = 1
    }
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(hb[17:], uint64(t.T2.f4))
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(hb[25:], uint64(t.T2.f5))
    if t.T2.f6 {
        hb[33] = 1
    }
    f := fnv.New64a()
    f.Write(hb)
    return f.Sum64()
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/xQs7wYCzfj)

Although if you are using it as a map key, it's better to just directly use the struct as the key and let go handle it.